# WinUI3 : How to get Aeroplane mode toggle event in WinUI3 desktop Application in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-runtime, winui-3, cppwinrt

I'm working of WinUI3 desktop application in C++. I was searching for a way to receive an event when user toggles airplane mode in windows.

I came across a way where where we can check Registry at

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\RadioManagement\SystemRadioState
```

with the help of [RegNotifyChangeKeyValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regnotifychangekeyvalue)

But in this way, we will receive an event handle from RegNotifyChangeKeyValue and have a worker thread continuously waiting for this event handler to be set.

Is there any other way to get the airplane mode toggle event instead of a thread continuously waiting on a register key event to happen?

It would be of great help if you could help me achieve this.

Thank you

Comment: That reads wrong. `RegNotifyChangeKeyValue` isn't *"continuously waiting"*. It waits exactly once, and if no changes happen the thread never gets scheduled to run. And while it's unclear from reading the question, what's the specific *issue* you are trying to solve here?

Comment: You can use WinRT's Radio.StateChanged Event https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.radios.radio.statechanged when you go airplain, the Radio.State becomes Off https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.radios.radiostate.

Comment: Thank you for your response @IInspectable, I have updated the question, RegNotifyChangeKeyValue will return immediately and it will give us an event handle, we have to wait on a worker thread continuously for this event handler to be set. The specific issue I'm trying to solve here is "I want to get an event when the user toggles airplane mode in windows"

Comment: Thank you for your response @SimonMourier, While searching for how to get the instance of the Radio class, I came across this( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.radios.radiokind?view=winrt-22621 ) different radio kind, it did not mention any radio kind for airplane mode. can you please help me with an example

Comment: Airplane mode is when the Wifi is Off (not Disabled).

Comment: I tried implementing it, I got RadioStateChange Event with radioKind wifi where RadioState is Off when I turned off the wifi, I got the same for airplane mode also [as toggling airplane mode toggles wifi]

Comment: How about using *Windows Events*? You can [subscribe to Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/subscribing-to-events) or [receive Event Notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/eventlog/receiving-event-notification). Also see the [question](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a0d8d131-9907-4bfd-b8b9-fb8fd98e8eeb/flight-mode-event-log).

Comment: Thank you @YangXiaoPo-MSFT, is the event ID in the event viewer constant for all the windows systems?

Comment: Normally, it is but that's not a guarantee.

Comment: EvtSubcribe - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winevt/nf-winevt-evtsubscribe takes a query that will specify the event to which we are subscribing. Can you please help me with the documentation on how to write this query, the only example that I was able to find was "Event/System[EventID=7012]",  As eventID is not guaranteed to be constant, please help me with a proper way to write a query

Comment: And the EventID 7011 and 7012 which are mentioned in the link you attached, I am able to get it for wifi toggle also. I'm not able to see any specific event entry in the Event Log specific to the airplane mode toggle